# How can I get a string copied in the method?

Tags: c, string, pointers, return, local

question：
Now I get a source string, I will to get a substring from it but not to broke it because the source string is used in furture.

test.cpp：

```
void method1(source,char* result)
{
   char temp[num];
   strcpy(temp,source); //copy the source string
   ...         //use temp
   result=target string；
}
void method2(source,char* result)
{
   char temp[num];
   strcpy(temp,source); //copy the source string
   ...         //use temp
   result=target string；
}
int main（)
{
   char source[];
   ...（maybe I declare some variables to save the result,e.g. char* result）
   method1（source,result）;
   method2（source,result);
}
```

this will not work because the copy variable 'temp' in the method willbe destroyed before retun.
I got a version which works:
The author use a struct to save the result:

```
typedef struct
{
   char* sub[50];
   uint32_t num;
}result_t;
```

It works in two seperate files:

desc_data_parser.h:

```
#ifndef _DESC_DATA_PARSER_H_
#define _DESC_DATA_PARSER_H_
#include <stdint.h>

class desc_data_parser
{
    public:

        static const uint32_t MAX_DESC_DATA_NUM=512;
        typedef struct
        {
            char* desc_result[MAX_DESC_DATA_NUM];
            uint32_t desc_result_num;
        }desc_result_t;

    public:

        static int lookup_value(char* source,char* key, desc_result_t* results);
        static int lookup_value_t(char* source,char* key, char* results);
};
#endif
```

desc_data_parser.cpp:

```
#ifndef _DESC_DATA_PARSER_
#define _DESC_DATA_PARSER_
#include "desc_data_parser.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int desc_data_parser::lookup_value(char* source, char* key, desc_result_t* results)
{
    printf("yourself\n");
    if((NULL == source) || ('\0' ==source[0]) || (NULL == key) || ('\0' == key[0]))
        return 0;
    int num = 0;
    //bzero(results,sizeof(desc_result_t));
    char copy_buf[2046]; //the source buf
    char* t_buf;
    strcpy(copy_buf,source);
    t_buf = copy_buf;
    //t_buf = strstr(t_buf,key); //keep the buf with key
     results->desc_result[0]=copy_buf;


    return num;

}
int desc_data_parser::lookup_value_t(char* source, char* key, char* results)
{
    printf("yourself\n");
    if((NULL == source) || ('\0' ==source[0]) || (NULL == key) || ('\0' == key[0]))
        return 0;
    int num = 0;
    char copy_buf[2046]; //the source buf
    char* t_buf;
    strcpy(copy_buf,source);
    t_buf = copy_buf;

     results=copy_buf;


    return num;

}
#endif
```

test2.cpp:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "desc_data_parser.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

  char* source="prod:fdafadfa";
  desc_data_parser::desc_result_t temp_result;
  memset(&temp_result,0,sizeof(desc_data_parser::desc_result_t));
  desc_data_parser::lookup_value(source, "prod:",&temp_result);
  printf("%s last result\n",temp_result.desc_result[0]); //why it works
  char result[50];
  desc_data_parser::lookup_value_t(source, "prod:",result);// why it not
  printf("%s last result\n",result);

}
```

I tried to merge test.cpp and test1.cpp together, howerer it does not work.

I got two questions:

1. why does the method above work?
2. Are there any difference between local-defined static methods and included static methods?

I updated the post and why these two caller get the defferent results?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? Looks like C to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C++, use std::string instead.

```
static void method2(source,result_t* result)
```

This won't even compile, what is the type of source?

Answer (score 1):

Just like you copy the source into the `temp` variable, you copy the target string into `result`. Remember to allocate enough space for the `result` string before calling your functions.

Also note that copying the `source` into `temp` like you do is cosidered bad and very prone to errors, since the string in `source` may be longer than the memory allocated for `temp`. A better implementation may be like this:

```
void method1(source,char* result, size_t result_max)
{
    char *temp = malloc(strlen(source) + 1);  /* +1 for the string terminator */
    strcpy(temp,source); //copy the source string
    ...         //use temp
    strncpy(result, <whatever>, result_max);
    free(temp);
}
```

And similar for the other functions.

Comment: The trick above does not maintain the heap but stacks. So I think it is an uncertain behavior. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with the split source files or not.  When you declare the char[] as a local in the main function (in your example as part of a struct but that's not required), it's being allocated on the stack for the duration of the main function, which includes the calls two the two methods.  When you utilize a temp array within the methods, that array is going out of scope when the method ends.  In order for your methods to pass data back they either need to store it in memory allocated prior to the function call or they need to allocate memory on the heap using malloc or new and return a pointer to that memory.  If they do allocate memory, you'll have to ensure it gets freed or deleted later.

Response to your follow up since the site is failing to submit my comment

The compiler won't "clean" the memory in question, but it will move the stack frame and the data will be overwritten on the next method call.  It's undefined behavior to access this memory after it goes out of scope as you'll very like corrupt the stack and end up crashing your program.

Comment: the program below is a segment online. Is there any possibility that the compiler does not clean when an non-local static method returns so the result can still visit the content in the stack?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, but it's not likely.  Static method or not, the stack is used again when the stack frame moves for the next method call.  At the assembly language level, static methods are no different than instance methods, they just have one less parameter (this)